# How can I change the inside of the modal pop up with the textbox on the main web page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do something with modal popups but I don't have too much knowledge about modal popups and their codes.

So I want to change the inside of the modal popup with the textbox which is on the main web page. I'll write something to the textbox then when I click the button, inside of the modal popup should be changed. And also there it is a textbox inside of the modal popup with button when I write something to textbox and hit enter paragraph of main web page should be changed too.

I tried something like this:

**HTML**

```
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<input type="text" id="to" value="Something">
<br>
<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

        <br>
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p id="demo">.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction(){
 var x = document.getElementById("to").innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
 }
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need this kind of an implementation.
Please run the example to see it in action.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

//Modal open function
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('to').value;
}

//Modal text update function
function udpateText() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = document.getElementById('from').value;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<p id="paragraph"></p>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<input type="text" id="to" value="Something">
<br>
<button id="myBtn" onclick="openModal()">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <br>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="demo">.</p>

    <input type="text" id="from" value="">
    <br>
    <button id="myModalBtn" onclick="udpateText()">Update Text</button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for solution that's the exactly what I want. But I couldn't add it to my code do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Copy CSS inside your `<style>` tag. Copy JavaScript code inside your `<script>` tag. Put HTML code inside your `<body>` tag. That should work fine.

Comment: tank you so much for your help and give your time :)

Answer (score 0):

here is an implementation using jquery ui modal.

this line puts the text input into the modal content.   `$('#content').text($('#myinput').val());`

here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8emj1ywp/1/